# Joda-Time, Time without date

Tags: java, jodatime

I want a Class that only stores the time and not the date or day. Is there a class for this in Joda-Time ? or do I have to use a Date time and convert only the time part into a string and then use that part ?

Comment: What is the problem with this question ? If there is a genuine problem, then i will delete it.

Comment: there's no problem, and it's a good question (+1 from me)

Comment: @Bozho - Off topic - what do you eat ? you're just 25 and you've done so much already. I am still stuck on hello world of joda time :)

Comment: -1 from me, for a lack of research. The 5 first lines of the quick start guide of joda time, linked from its home page, give you the answer you want.

Comment: @JBNizet that's another story, yes. I gave +1 because I didn't know the answer..then I found it quickly :)

Comment: @JediKnight I started early ;)

Comment: @JBNizet - Yes. I saw the quick start guide. Did not know it was there. I went straight to the API's. Quick start guide here  - http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's the [`LocalTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) class for that purpose.

Read more about [partials here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_partial.html). E.g.:

```
LocalTime time = new LocalTime(12, 20);
String formatted = time.toString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: Thanks and gimme some of your secret sauce :)

Comment: Since JodaTime 2.0, it's possible to use [LocalTime#parse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28530181/363573)

Answer (score 4):

`LocalTime` - Immutable class representing a time without a date (no time zone)

Check out [this](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html)

Comment: @JediKnight:- I strongly agree :)

Answer (score 0):

Since JodaTime 2.0, it's also possible to instanciate a time without date like this:

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse( //
      "12h20", //
       DateTimeFormatter.forPattern("HH'h'mm") //
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 now has its own [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class. No need for an external library.