# How to Strip Date from Calendar?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I need to Strip a Date from a Calendar. I have something like that: 'DD/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' but I need just the time ('HH:mm:ss').

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363307/getting-the-time-component-of-a-java-date-or-calendar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to format the date, you can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
    .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

this prints something like:

```
20:20:11
```

---

**EDIT**

I suggest you use  [java.sql.Time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) and a [PreparedStatement#setTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTime%28int,%20java.sql.Time%29) to build your criteria

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Time time = new Time(cal.getTime().getTime());
pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from mytable where t=?");
pst.setTime(1, time);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getTime("t"));
}
```

Comment: I need the time to make a MySQL select

Comment: @iknunes how to you save the time in the data base/ which type has the table column?

Comment: It's a TIME. I have a Calendar with 'DD/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' then I need a DATE with 'HH:mm:ss' to compare in my criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The below code would strip off DD/MM/yyyy and print only the Hour Minute and seconds.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
public class JavaUtilTimeTester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Calendar:"+cal.toString());
    Date d=cal.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(d));
    SimpleDateFormat sdfNew=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(sdfNew.format(d));
} 
}
```